# How do I restrict API access to only my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I've created an api and implemented JWT for certain actions. I followed a few tutorials and have successfully prevented unauthorized requests to non-GET endpoints. Each of the tutorials seems to cover the same concept though: Making requests for a User. That is, I'm getting their username/password, requesting a token, validating that token, then performing the actions.

The issue is that I don't want the public to be able to make `GET` requests to the api. I also don't want them to be logging into the application since it's not necessary.

I'll probably be using some ajax on the site as well, I'm not sure if that complicates things.

Am I supposed to just make each request using an "application" username/password? Or is there a standard way to limit api requests to an application?

Comment: I recommend reading up on the different types of [OAuth2 workflows](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use).

Comment: Do you want "the public" to do anything at all? Maybe it's easier to solve this through network routing. If only your machines can reach the server, that's way better than any software mechanism.

Comment: @nvoigt The public won't be modifying any data or anything. There is a form that will display different results but that is about it. Essentially what I'm trying to do is lock down the data that gets returned from the GET requests. It's not that the data needs to be private, but I'd rather not expose it publicly if I can avoid it.

I will however, eventually want to add in an admin section that will allow me to make changes to the data.

Comment: @Amy I'll get right on that. I don't have much experience using OAuth.

Comment: Why don't you just request authorization for all of the actions?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 I'm sure that's what I need to do. What I'm not sure of is how to properly authenticate my application for the api. It seems silly to hardcode a username/password and request a jwt for each request. But maybe that's what is normally done?

Comment: Wait wait - give some code, otherwise we can get in to the deep.. you know. Lets simplify the things a bit - show what you are doing at the moment.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Unfortunately, I don't think I'm going about it the right way with JWT, so I feel adding code would only confuse the issue. I'm thinking that a solution _like_ an OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant would be a good solution, but honestly it seems like implementing OAuth2 here could be overkill.

Comment: @gin93r - you can always go for a custom OAuth2 implementation (like IdentityServer4 for example)

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 That looks promising. I'll look into it some more. Thanks for the suggestion :D

Comment: So your app is available to everyone ( login not required ) and is static in the sense that APIs will be same for all users ( response of end points ) ?

Comment: @SabirKhan Currently yes. With a later option of adding in an administrative tool. It seems like IdentityServer is the best option so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your scenario I'd say you want to consider IdentityServer for sure.

This will allow you to skip most of the complexity behind OAuth2. I've seen a lot of people mention that the OAuth2 flow is overkill, but it is a standard and if you spend some time to understand it then you'll see it's not actually that hard.

How will this work in your case?

You want to go with the application authentication since you don't care about the users logging in. This means you will define a ClientID and ClientSecret combination, this will help identify one application. If you have more than one application simply create more combinations.

You will issue an initial request to an Authorization Server, passing the ClientID and CLientSecret in a Basic Authorization header.

You will get back a token which allows you to access your resources for a defined period of time. You access your resources using a Bearer Authorization header this time with the token you received from your Authorization Server.

That's it, basically. A good resource is [Taiseer's blog](http://bitoftech.net/taiseer-joudeh-blog/). I strongly recommend it as this guy is a Microsoft MVP and has done a lot of work in this particular area.

I have an older article using Identity v3. It's out of date now but it does explain everything in detail, so you might want to take a look at that as well :

[Andrei's article](https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/)

I would recommend staying away from any custom security systems as those are not battle hardened and not really proven in the wild. It's very easy to expose yourself with one tiny mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I've been playing around with IdentityServer4 a bit since this I posted this and I think you're right. I still need to wrap my head around it to make sure, but as you said, it's not that difficult.

Answer (score -1):

What we're talking about here seems to be **authorzing** each GET request based on the user's identity.

Getting the username and password, requesting the token and validating the token is all **authentication**. Sounds to me like what you want to do next is authorization, which covers "what a user can do".

In order to authorize requests you'll need a mechanism to identify what each user/groups of users can and cannot do and querying this at the individual GET end point to ascertain whether the user should be allowed to make the request and if not returning the appropriate 403 Forbidden response.

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET you can prevent such request by enabling CORS features. 
First of all you need to Install "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" package, using Nuget Manager. Then modify your WebApiConfig file as per below.

```
public static class WebApiConfig  
{  
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)  
    {  
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:18479", "*", "*");  
        config.EnableCors(cors);  
        // Web API configuration and services  

        // Web API routes  
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new {  
        id = RouteParameter.Optional });  
    }  
}
```

you can enable cors per action, per controller. the above sample will enable cors globally.